# не отображается спрайт-компонент vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svg, svg-спрайт

Есть спрайт-компонент SvgSprite.vue :

```
<template>
<div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" style="display: none;">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 98.624 98.624" id="instagram">
    <g>
    <path d="M62.161,24.47H36.218c-6.492,0-11.774,5.282-11.774,11.774v26.181c0,6.492,5.282,11.774,11.774,11.774h25.943
        c6.492,0,11.774-5.282,11.774-11.774V36.244C73.935,29.752,68.653,24.47,62.161,24.47z M49.239,65.011
        c-8.8,0-15.959-7.083-15.959-15.789c0-8.706,7.16-15.789,15.959-15.789s15.959,7.083,15.959,15.789
        C65.198,57.928,58.039,65.011,49.239,65.011z M65.482,36.542c-2.074,0-3.755-1.681-3.755-3.755c0-2.074,1.681-3.755,3.755-3.755
        c2.074,0,3.755,1.681,3.755,3.755C69.237,34.861,67.556,36.542,65.482,36.542z"/>
    <path d="M49.312,0C22.078,0,0,22.078,0,49.312s22.078,49.312,49.312,49.312s49.312-22.078,49.312-49.312S76.546,0,49.312,0z
        M79.759,62.425c0,9.704-7.895,17.598-17.598,17.598H36.218c-9.704,0-17.598-7.895-17.598-17.598V36.244
        c0-9.704,7.895-17.598,17.598-17.598h25.943c9.704,0,17.598,7.895,17.598,17.598V62.425z"/>
    <path d="M49.239,39.246c-5.595,0-10.146,4.475-10.146,9.976c0,5.501,4.551,9.976,10.146,9.976c5.595,0,10.146-4.475,10.146-9.976
        C59.385,43.721,54.834,39.246,49.239,39.246z"/>
</g>
  </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 98.624 98.624" id="behance">
      <g>
    <path d="M67.783,44.689c-1.985,0-3.518,0.571-4.607,1.694c-1.097,1.12-1.779,2.644-2.058,4.572h13.306
        c-0.145-2.052-0.83-3.606-2.064-4.667C71.136,45.224,69.607,44.689,67.783,44.689z"/>
    <path d="M38.662,52.477c-0.977-0.452-2.356-0.682-4.123-0.699h-8.85v10.988h8.713c1.79,0,3.175-0.234,4.175-0.723
        c1.803-0.899,2.707-2.609,2.707-5.149C41.284,54.752,40.409,53.271,38.662,52.477z"/>
    <path d="M38.772,43.93c1.115-0.68,1.672-1.889,1.672-3.625c0-1.918-0.737-3.191-2.215-3.803c-1.27-0.426-2.895-0.645-4.867-0.645
        h-7.674v9.095h8.724C36.206,44.952,37.656,44.611,38.772,43.93z"/>
    <path d="M49.312,0C22.078,0,0,22.078,0,49.312s22.078,49.312,49.312,49.312s49.312-22.078,49.312-49.312S76.546,0,49.312,0z
        M59.418,30.408h16.604v4.124h-0.001H59.418V30.408z M48.14,64.061c-0.781,1.283-1.751,2.366-2.917,3.238
        c-1.313,1.009-2.867,1.7-4.653,2.07c-1.792,0.37-3.732,0.557-5.821,0.557H16.181v-41.23h19.912
        c5.019,0.082,8.577,1.536,10.678,4.392c1.261,1.751,1.885,3.853,1.885,6.296c0,2.521-0.632,4.538-1.905,6.07
        c-0.708,0.859-1.754,1.641-3.139,2.346c2.098,0.768,3.69,1.977,4.753,3.642c1.071,1.659,1.607,3.674,1.607,6.039
        C49.971,59.929,49.368,62.123,48.14,64.061z M82.435,56.05H60.932c0.119,2.968,1.143,5.044,3.086,6.231
        c1.172,0.745,2.593,1.109,4.257,1.109c1.754,0,3.184-0.444,4.285-1.355c0.6-0.483,1.129-1.165,1.586-2.026h7.881
        c-0.206,1.753-1.155,3.531-2.861,5.338c-2.642,2.872-6.348,4.312-11.107,4.312c-3.932,0-7.396-1.214-10.404-3.634
        c-2.997-2.429-4.503-6.367-4.503-11.831c0-5.123,1.352-9.045,4.064-11.774c2.722-2.735,6.235-4.096,10.566-4.096
        c2.567,0,4.88,0.459,6.945,1.381c2.058,0.923,3.758,2.376,5.098,4.373c1.212,1.759,1.992,3.792,2.355,6.109
        C82.381,51.535,82.472,53.492,82.435,56.05z"/>
</g>
    </symbol>
    <symbol viewBox="0 0 98.624 98.624" id="linkedin">
<path d="M54.585,41.708v-0.116c-0.024,0.038-0.055,0.079-0.078,0.116H54.585z"/>
<path d="M49.312,0C22.078,0,0,22.078,0,49.312s22.078,49.312,49.312,49.312s49.312-22.078,49.312-49.312S76.546,0,49.312,0z
    M36.108,72.304H24.213V36.52h11.895V72.304z M30.161,31.637h-0.08c-3.99,0-6.576-2.751-6.576-6.186
    c0-3.511,2.663-6.182,6.734-6.182s6.574,2.67,6.652,6.182C36.891,28.887,34.311,31.637,30.161,31.637z M79.007,72.304H67.111V53.159
    c0-4.809-1.721-8.091-6.026-8.091c-3.287,0-5.243,2.212-6.104,4.352c-0.314,0.765-0.395,1.83-0.395,2.9v19.984h-11.9
    c0,0,0.16-32.425,0-35.784h11.898v5.072c1.581-2.435,4.404-5.913,10.723-5.913c7.829,0,13.698,5.114,13.698,16.106v20.519H79.007z"
    />
    </symbol>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 320 512" id="facebook">
<path d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"></path>
    </symbol>
        <symbol viewBox="0 0 63.918 54.832" id="telegram">
      <path d="M61.889,0.103L0.933,23.34c-1.228,0.477-1.245,2.384-0.047,2.931L16.5,32.675l5.815,18.34
    c0.346,0.988,1.577,1.32,2.372,0.639l8.931-8.311l16.979,11.261c0.881,0.551,2.042,0.053,2.248-0.965l11.04-51.852
    C64.121,0.633,62.986-0.323,61.889,0.103z M25.183,36.148l-0.992,9.428l-4.714-14.513L52.722,9.231L25.183,36.148z"/>
    </symbol>
  </svg>
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="share">
    <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
    <path d="M18 16.08c-.76 0-1.44.3-1.96.77L8.91 12.7c.05-.23.09-.46.09-.7s-.04-.47-.09-.7l7.05-4.11c.54.5 1.25.81 2.04.81 1.66 0 3-1.34 3-3s-1.34-3-3-3-3 1.34-3 3c0 .24.04.47.09.7L8.04 9.81C7.5 9.31 6.79 9 6 9c-1.66 0-3 1.34-3 3s1.34 3 3 3c.79 0 1.5-.31 2.04-.81l7.12 4.16c-.05.21-.08.43-.08.65 0 1.61 1.31 2.92 2.92 2.92 1.61 0 2.92-1.31 2.92-2.92s-1.31-2.92-2.92-2.92z"/>
  </symbol>
        <!-- <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#behance"></use>
    </svg> -->
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SvgSprite',
}
</script>
```

Я его импортирую в другой компонент, а он не отображается:

```
<template>
        <footer :class="['footer', {'right': this.$store.state.currentTitle === 'not'}]">
        <div class="social-block">
            <div class="social-link">
             <SvgSprite/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</template>

<script>
import SvgSprite from './SvgSprite'
export default {
    name: 'Footer',
    components:
    { SvgSprite : SvgSprite},
    data: () => ({
        main: require("../assets/img/social/share.svg"),
        show: true,
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: У svg инлайн стиль display:none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если фрагменты кода SVG в спрайте обернуты `<symbol>`, то иконки становятся невидимыми, пока они не будут вызваны с помощью `<use>` по id соответствующего `<symbol>`

У вас, как раз закомментирована часть такого кода

```
<!-- <svg class="icon">
        <use xlink:href="#behance"></use>
    </svg> -->
```

Вполне вероятно, что из-за этого не отображаются иконки.